# How to Add OAuth Login Functionality to an Asp.net Membership website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, oauth, scalability

I have a web application which currently has a bunch of users and use `Asp.net` Membership to create and manage users.

I want to add "OAuth" functionality to my application and want to still using  ASP.net Membership (login, etc.), and I also want my user login to application with any public social network ID, if that network use a OAuth membership.

How can I use Asp.net and OAuth (`open ID`)  beside each other?

I also want to add a new page for users to create a profile for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> openid

Take a look at the [OpenIDMembershipProvider](http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/). Also [Nerddinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/49328#440017) has OpenID implemented (in MVC not MembershipProvider).

Answer (score 0):

New templates in Visual Studio 2012 has OAuth out of the box. To see how those are implemented, just create sample project.

These templates uses DotNetOpenAuth as a client library:
http://www.dotnetopenauth.net

Here is Hansleman's video on new features:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx
this link has a project template which shows how you can add oauth functionality to your asp.net membership provider